# Validation error unable to open URLFOR page

Tags: apex, visualforce, urlfor

I have a custom VFP with few validations on it and when the user submit the page it run through validations and display any errors (if any)

But the problem I'm having is that whenever there are some validations error on the page then I'm unable to open the `outputlink` otherwise I do not have any issue with opening/clicking the link and open the page.

Visualforce page:

```
   <apex:pageBlockTable Title="Employees" value="{!Employees}" var="item">
     <apex:column headerValue="Name" >
       <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Employee__c.View, item.empId)}">{!item.Name}</apex:outputLink>
     </apex:column>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

What might be the issue that triggers not to open the `URLFOR` page?

> What happens when you click on the link:

When click on the link, I see white page with nothing on it and the url i see is this https://..../apex/employeeView?id=a004B000001gDiA&sfdc.override=1

Screen shot of my View button/link. showing that its standard sf page:

[image]

Comment: can you change the outputlink to a commandlink? if so you can try using immediate attribute https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm

Comment: Sounds like your `EmployeeView` page is messed up and it has nothing to do with the markup you have posted. Just my two cents.

Comment: @AdrianLarson:  `EmployeeView` is a standard page layout if the page is messed up then it should not open before validation error throws an error.

Comment: No, you have clearly implemented an override on the `View` action. Go to `Buttons, Links, and Actions` on the `Employee__c` object and clear it out to see the difference for yourself.

Comment: I'm not overriding the view page, `View - Standard Salesforce.com Page`

Comment: The url plainly contradicts that assertion. `/apex/MyVisualforcePageName?parameters=values` means you are using an override.

Comment: If you truly aren't using an override, you need to open a ticket with support, because this sounds like a bug.

Comment: the URL that I have posted its happening after the validation error throws and then I try to click the link, I have added screen shot of my`Buttons, Links, and Actions` showing that its standard page

Comment: What happens when you fill out your url manually? ie just try to visit the Employee page manually? Perhaps someone else created an override that's breaking things for you.

Comment: if i fill out url manually and past it on the browser and hit enter i able to see the page without any issues

Comment: I think you are not explaining something critical that is going on here.